# How to extract the value of the item Interest over term using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I need to reach this element in selenium I think it is angular so chropath plugin is not showing any data to reach here. and extract value 14,213.47
its inside iframe

```
 <div class="elem">
                            <span class="text">Interest over term</span>
                            <span class="value">$14,213.47</span>
                        </div>
```

how can I write xpath or cssselector for it to reach this element

```
<div class="calculator-output">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="img-Mortgage"></div>
        <!---->
        <!----><span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Mortgage Payment:</span>
        <!---->
    </div>

    <!----><div class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

                <div class="output">

                    
                    <!---->
                    
                    
                    <!---->
                    
                    
                    <!---->
                    
                    
                    <!----><div class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">
                        <!----><div class="elem ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">
                            <span class="text">Mortgage Payment</span>
                            <span class="value">$1,867.73</span>
                        </div>
                        <!---->
                        
                        <div class="elem">
                            <span class="text">Interest over term</span>
                            <span class="value">$14,213.47</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="elem">
                            <span class="text">Balance owing at term</span>
                            <span class="value">$341,800.71</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="elem">
                            <span class="text">
                                Total interest
                                <span class="info-tooltip" data-balloon="Total interest cost over amortization."></span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="value">$210,318.94</span>
                        </div>

                        <!---->
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <!---->
                    <!---->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="options">
                    <div class="elem">
                        <div class="imgPlan"></div>
                        <span class="ng-tns-c0-0">Full Plan</span>
                    </div>
                    <!----><div class="elem ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">
                        <div class="imgPrint"></div>
                        <span class="ng-tns-c0-0">Print</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="elem">
                        <div class="imgSave"></div>
                        <span class="ng-tns-c0-0">Save</span>
                    </div>
                    <!----><div class="elem ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">
                        <div class="imgCompare"></div>
                        <span class="ng-tns-c0-0">Compare</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text **Interest over term** and the associated value **$14,213.47** are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.coastcapitalsavings.com/calculators/mortgage-calculator")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cookies-disclaimer--button']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://calculator.coastcapitalsavings.com/ITSCredit.External/CCS/ITSCredit.CCS.UI.External/calculator/MT?']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Payment']"))).click()
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Interest over term']"))))
  # using xpath and text attribute
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Interest over term']//following-sibling::span"))).text)
  # using cssSelector and get_attribute()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Interest over term']//following-sibling::span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  $4,819.69
  $4,819.69
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 0):

To select the `<div>`, use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//div[@class="elem" and span[@class="text"]="Interest over term"]
```

and to get the value `14,213.47`, use this one:

```
substring-after(//div[@class="elem" and span[@class="text"]="Interest over term"]/span[2],"$")
```

Comment: When I open this page, I cannot even find the term `Interest over term`, so it's no wonder the expression doesn't work. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: I guess that @DebanjanB's answer will be better than mine, because I do not know about extracting data from IFRAMEs. Maybe my XPath'es are of some use for you, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try either

```
(//div[@class="elem"]/span["interest over term"])[1]/following-sibling::span[@class="value"]
```

or

```
(//div[@class="elem"]/span["interest over term"])[1]/following-sibling::span[@class="value"]/text()
```

and see if it works.